# Installing React-Redux causes the chokidar Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hello guys I keep on getting the error below when I try to install react-redux

```
Error from chokidar (/home/lamechdesai/Projects/WebApp/JavaScript/React_JS/Clydan/flexanalytics_frontend/flexanalytics_frontend/src/views/Reports/Financial): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/lamechdesai/Projects/WebApp/JavaScript/React_JS/Clydan/flexanalytics_frontend/flexanalytics_frontend/src/views/Reports/Financial/ReportsRevenueAccountDivisionMonthSubClass.js'
```

Comment: Did you try googling for the error? Googling "chokidar system limit for number of file watchers reached" yields this issue, with many possible solutions for different OSes. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7612

Comment: Thanks I solved it by running "npm install && npm clean-install react-scripts " command or this might bring a problem later?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Remove your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.
2. Clean npm cache `npm cache clean --force`
3. You can verify by `npm cache verify`.
4. Update npm `sudo npm i -g npm` - this is the key step, it should reinstall chokidar.
5. Install node_modules again by running `npm i --force`